# How can I properly setup Google Analytics in my Vue website?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, vuetify.js

I have 1 component called calculator.vue and in my main.js I have the code for the plugin, like below:

````
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import "./plugins/vuetify-money.js"
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics'

Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
 id: 'My UA',
 disableScriptLoader: true
})


Vue.use(VueMeta);

Vue.config.productionTip = false


new Vue({
 vuetify,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told here: https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics

> his plugin will stop receiving feature requests. I will only spend time for important bug fixes. Google moved from analytics.js to its new gtag.js library and I've created a new plugin called vue-gtag. I suggest you to start using that one if you are about to create a new project.

You can see an example here: https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/#add-plugin-to-your-application

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";

Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: "UA-1234567-1" }
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Thank you, works now with the new plugin. Should have read it through.